# No permissions after installation of plastic scm

Tags: plasticscm

after about 2 months, I installed plastic on a new laptop (because old laptop is not working anymore). I configured everything as defaulted and also let the authentication mode "Local name".

On nearly every operation I get: "The user salda appears as an inactive user because his/her license has been deactivated. Please activate it and then try again."

When I try **cm li** I get:

```
salda                     ACTIVE
about 10 other users      INACTIVE (Not licensed)
salda                     INACTIVE (Not licensed)
```

When I try either try **cm au salda** or **cm du salda**, I get: "You don't have permissions to (de)activate user salda. You need to be repository server administrator in order to be allowed to complete this operation."

I already had problems setting up plastic in the past: 
[Can't start using git repo in plasticscm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40772576/cant-start-using-git-repo-in-plasticscm), so I tried to find answer there and there is:

```
"It's important to note that all the commands to manage licenses are
only available if you are the server administrator user, so if you
haven't configured yet your admin user, please drive to the
Repositories & Workspaces view, right-click Repository server
permissions and mark your user as the owner."
```

, but I can't do that operation, because I don't see any repository and I also can't add any. It tells me again: "The user salda appears as an inactive user because his/her license has been deactivated. Please activate it and then try again."

How to fix this situation?

And I also tried to apply for both Personal and Community Edition and after those 2 months I don't have any response (not even rejection), is it possible to get one? I want to use plastic for displaying git repositories and handling branches, because I hate git tools for that, even SourceTree is totally shitty compared to plastic. I sometimes contribute to plastic forum, share photos and comment posts on plastic facebook page and also worked with paid plastic in the past for 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

I think due to your GitSync operations you ended up with duplicated users, one created in Plastic SCM the other one in Git, unfortunately there's no tool to fix the duplicated entries, but don't worry, we can easily edit the Plastic SCM database and change the name of one of them

I'll describe the process for the SQLite backend as it's the default database backend provided by the Plastic SCM installation, if you are using a different one you just need to follow the steps below using a proper SQL manager for your backend, [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com) for MySQL or [SQL Server Management Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/mt238290.aspx) for SQL Server.

[SQLiteBrowser](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) allows you to open SQLite databases and edit their content in a very easy way. Click on the "Open Database" button and start selecting the repositories database ("**repositories.plastic.sqlite**"), you'll find it inside the Plastic SCM server directory: *c:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server*

Once the database is loaded click on the "Browse data" tab, we want to edit the "**seid**" database, so please select it. This is what I get:
[image]

If you have don't see duplicated entries (as I do) you'll need to start opening the independent repositories databases one by one until you find the issue. The Plastic SCM repositories databases are named "**rep_1.plastic.sqlite**", "**rep_2.plastic.sqlite**" ...

In my scenario I found the *c:\Program Files\PlasticSCM5\server\rep_2.plastic.sqlite* database is having duplicated entries:

[image]

The "*tester*" user is added twice, we need to change one of them. SQLiteBrowser allows you directly change the cell value and store the changes by clicking on the "Write Changes" button.

Once the change is done you can restart your Plastic SCM server service and continue working.